# Validate field inputs against correct answers on button click with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am buiding a test-checking app, that compares field inputs against the correct answers.

When the user has done filling all the fields and then presses the "Check" button:

- in case the answer in any field is incorrect, such answer should change its text color to red;
- in case the answer in any field is correct, such answer should change its text color to green;

More so, a field appears on click and shows n/10 correct answers, so it is required to store the number of fields, that passed/did not pass validation.

I was trying to do that with Formik+Yup, yet the suggested approaches do not really come together when I am trying to apply it for my task.

**Here is a piece of code:**

```
const correctAnswers = [
    { id: "1", name: "1", correctAnswer: "Three times" },
    { id: "2", name: "2", correctAnswer: "Amazing weather" },
    { id: "3", name: "3", correctAnswer: "Town Hall" },
    { id: "4", name: "4", correctAnswer: "Variety" },
    { id: "5", name: "5", correctAnswer: "Plane" },
    { id: "6", name: "6", correctAnswer: "Over forty" },
    { id: "7", name: "7", correctAnswer: "Mid-range" },
    { id: "8", name: "8", correctAnswer: "Tourism" },
    { id: "9", name: "9", correctAnswer: "Computer programmer" },
    { id: "10", name: "10", correctAnswer: "Good value" },
  ];

<Formik>
  <Form>
    <div className="test-form-window">    
  
      {correctAnswers.map((answer) => {
        return (
          <div className="test-field">
            <Field
              key={answer.correctAnswer}
              className="test-field-input"
              type="text"
              id={answer.id}
              name={answer.id}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>

    <div className="test-results">`You have scored ( ${numberOfCorrectAnswers} / 10 )`</div>

    <div className="form-controls">
      <button className="check-button" onClick={handleCheck}> {/* supposed to do the described above */}
        Check
      </button>
      <button className="show-button" onClick={handleShow}>  {/* fills input fields with correct answers */}
        Show
      </button>
      <button className="clear-button" onClick={handleClear}> {/* clears field values */}
        Clear
      </button>
    </div>

  </Form>
</Formik>
```

I was thinking about adding a field validation function for the Fields (as per Manually Triggering Validation in the docs), but cannot really figure it out.

```
const validateField = (e) => {
  ...some code...
}

{correctAnswers.map((answer) => {
  return (
    <div className="test-field">
      <Field
        ...
        validate={validateField}
        ...
      />
    </div>
  );
})}

validate
```

**Any suggestions/leads for a solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected behaviour can be achieved via `FieldArray` with `validationSchema` . Since you are mapping over a list to render we can use the `FieldArray` from Formik to render the `Field` and for handling `validation` as well.

Have created code sandbox using your example .

[FieldArray Validation Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-williamson-e1zxr?file=/src/App.js:222-237)

Type any value in the field apart from the correct answer you will see the message `wrong answer` getting populated next to your Input Field .

Now type the correct answer for that field . You should see the `correct answer` getting populated next to your Input Field .

**Reference**

[FieldArray](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `yup` before you write your own validation logic. Im quite sure they have a solution to your problem. Once you wrote up your field validation scheme, you can use it in your Formik component like:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
```

validationSchema in formik: https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validationschema

yup: https://github.com/jquense/yup